# Check Cisco switch congestion

Tags: networking, cisco

How can I check if Cisco switch (2960) does loose packets (e.g. because of congestion)?

What are tools/commands for troubleshooting such issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `show int` and `show int summary` commands should give you enough information to at least see if you are having problems on a particular port.

The `show int summary` command will give you an overview of each interface's input/output hold queue as well as the current bits and packets per second counts and the number of packets dropped from the input/output queues.

```
  #show int summary

 *: interface is up
 IHQ: pkts in input hold queue     IQD: pkts dropped from input queue
 OHQ: pkts in output hold queue    OQD: pkts dropped from output queue
 RXBS: rx rate (bits/sec)          RXPS: rx rate (pkts/sec)
 TXBS: tx rate (bits/sec)          TXPS: tx rate (pkts/sec)
 TRTL: throttle count

  Interface                   IHQ       IQD       OHQ       OQD      RXBS      RXPS      TXBS      TXPS      TRTL
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Vlan1                         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* Vlan2                         1         0         0         0      6000         8      6000         4         0
  FastEthernet0                 0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/1          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/2          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/3          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/4          0         0         0         0      9000         4    190000        19         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/5          0         0         0         0      3000         2     36000        15         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/6          0         0         0         0      3000         2     17000        13         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/7          0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/8          0         0         0         0    114000         7    196000        30         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/9          0         0         0         0    136000        32    270000        43         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/10         0         0         0         0      7000         8    254000        27         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/11         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/12         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/13         0         0         0        15      1000         0     16000        13         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/14         0         0         0         0      1000         1     13000        12         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/15         0         0         0         0      1000         1     14000        12         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/16         0         0         0         0         0         0     36000         6         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/17         0         0         0         0      8000        10     35000        43         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/18         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/19         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/20         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/21         0         0         0         0     23000        32     20000        22         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/22         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/23         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/24         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/25         0         0         0         0         0         0     78000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/26         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/27         0         0         0         0      7000         4    215000        20         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/28         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/29         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/30         0         0         0         0      1000         1     13000        13         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/31         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/32         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        13         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/33         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/34         0         0         0         0     51000        30    434000        56         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/35         0         0         0         0         0         0     61000        14         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/36         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        11         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/37         0         0         0         0         0         0    172000        42         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/38         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        12         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/39         0         0         0         0         0         0     12000        12         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/40         0         0         0         0    491000       832  63201000      5869         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/41         0         0         0         0      1000         1     13000        13         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/42         0         0         0         0     28000         3     62000        17         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/43         0         0         0         0         0         0    112000        12         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/44         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
* GigabitEthernet1/0/45         0         0         0         0         0         0     14000        15         0
  GigabitEthernet1/0/46         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0
 --More--
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a `show interfaces`, for example, the example below.  You should be able to see what interfaces (if any) are showing packet errors, at which point you'd need to do some troubleshooting or diagnostics to determine why.

```
[some-switch-thing]#sh int
FastEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up
  Hardware is Gt96k FE, address is [some-MAC-address-thing] (bia some-MAC-address-thing)
  Internet address is [some-IP-address-thing]
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 100 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  Keepalive set (10 sec)
  Full-duplex, 100Mb/s, 100BaseTX/FX
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 00:00:01, output 00:00:00, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 112000 bits/sec, 51 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 207000 bits/sec, 46 packets/sec
     329320347 packets input, 534153518 bytes
     Received 4483582 broadcasts, 0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     0 watchdog
     0 input packets with dribble condition detected
     320121443 packets output, 1884667704 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 0 collisions, 3 interface resets
     0 babbles, 0 late collision, 0 deferred
     0 lost carrier, 0 no carrier
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

Comment: It's a very good place to start!